# What is findDOMNode and it is deprecated in StrictMode in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to make a count up using react visibility sensor and react count up, but when I tried to set it up an error shows in the console. Is there a  proper way to solve?

**Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of VisibilitySensor which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.**

My code is

```
<div className="App">
 <VisibilitySensor partialVisibility offset={{ bottom: 200 }}>
        {({ isVisible }) => (
          <div style={{ height: 100 }}>
            {isVisible ? <CountUp duration={5} start={0} end={1000} /> : null}
          </div>
        )}
      </VisibilitySensor>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/joshwnj/react-visibility-sensor/issues/141) on the react-visibility-sensor repo, but the whole project seems to be not maintained any longer (last commit was in 2019).

I'm not a user of the plugin, but some people suggest moving to [react-intersection-observer](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer) as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your information